# how to force Maven 3.1 to use right version of Java on Mac OS 8.10?

Tags: java, macos, maven, conflict

This is the output from java -version:

java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

This is the output from mvn -version:

Java version: 1.6.0_51, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

How do I force Maven to use 1.7?

Answer (score 20):

Bug in Maven: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4226

Workaround:

echo JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` | sudo tee -a /etc/mavenrc

Thanks to:

http://www.jayway.com/2013/03/08/configuring-maven-to-use-java-7-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: I had to do the same for Java 1.8 on mac os 10.9 : echo `JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8*` | sudo tee -a /etc/mavenrc`

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (at least), Maven uses `$JAVA_HOME` to locate the JVM it uses to run.  Check that you have exported that environment variable, and that it points at the right place.