# Can't get Maven to recognize Java 1.8

Tags: java, maven

I can't seem to be able to get Maven to use Java 1.8. Using 1.8 as the target turns up the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
(default-compile) on project csaro: Fatal error compiling: invalid target
release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
```

The cause of the error is obvious enough: Maven isn't using the right version of Java:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T07:51:42-06:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.2/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

But the installed version of Java should be 1.8:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_20-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-ea-b22)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b21, mixed mode)
```

And JAVA_HOME is set:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I also tried the [command here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824889/how-to-force-maven-3-1-to-use-right-version-of-java-on-mac-os-8-10) (which creates `mavenrc`). I've tried restarting the computer several times, and have verified that the env var is correctly set (it's set in `.bash_profile`).

Maven was installed with Homebrew.

Java 1.8 is working fine in Eclipse (which is using m2e). I just can't get Maven to work on the command line.

Comment: _jdk1.8.0_20_ hasn't released yet, and i don't see ea in dir name, are you sure directory exist ?

Comment: Check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144660/what-is-path-of-jdk-on-mac.

Comment: @JigarJoshi, it's the early access version from [here](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

Comment: does it have java compiler `ls -la /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac` ?

Comment: Have you saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503658/specify-jdk-for-maven-to-use?

Comment: @Fede I believe that the value for JAVA_HOME is correct. `which java` returns `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`, which is the same path being used for JAVA_HOME.

Comment: can you `cat` your `mvn`  is it resetting `JAVA_HOME` ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi, output is [here](http://pastebin.com/8SYj4XQa).

Comment: can you try echoing it right before java invocation ? just to verify

Comment: @JigarJoshi, I found the value being overridden in `~/.mavenrc` (noticed that when I was inspecting the source of `mvn`).

Comment: @Mike that was tricky (I added it as an answer)

Comment: @hd1, I think my answer was the best fit (it actually solved it, although JigarJoshi's answer probably would have found the issue, too). However, I cannot accept my own answer for 2 days. Although I'm also open to other answers, if there's a "better way" to avoid these kinds of problems (values being set in multiple places).

Comment: Set it on command line -- `env JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/ /path/to/maven/bin/mvn` -- the problem is that you then need to remember to add it in every time.

Comment: i had to turn off rootless `https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11`

Comment: For me, upgrading from Maven 3.2.5 to 3.3.3 did the trick.

Comment: Similar problem and had JDK 1.8 / JAVA_HOME set to 1.8 / eclipse.ini pointed to JDK 1.8, still could not get it worked. Finally, ran mvn install from command line and voila, it works. That means m2e requires some tweak in configurations I reckon. Need to do some work to get this working in eclipse.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It turns out that I had a forgotten `~/.mavenrc` file that had set the value of `JAVA_HOME`.

For future readers, check the following locations for places that may override `JAVA_HOME` (in ascending order of precedence):

- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.profile`
- `/etc/mavenrc`
- `~/.mavenrc`

Comment: I couldn't find the place where `JAVA_HOME` is set (incorrectly) - I tried the ones you list, plus many more (/etc/environment, /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/*, ...). In the end I decided to put `unset JAVA_HOME` to my `~/.bashrc` - that's currently probably the only way to make it work automatically with Ubuntu's `update-alternatives` in most cases (since most programs try to figure out the correct JAVA_HOME on their own if it is not set and one of the first things they try is to look where the java executable points to).

Comment: If you can unset it, you should also be able to simply override the existing value.

Comment: If I set JAVA_HOME in ~/.bashrc it will be set for the whole session and won't change if I run update-alternatives and stay in the same session. I want most of the apps, and especially maven at this moment, to choose the JVM version set by update-alternatives. Unfortunately, Ubuntu doesn't consider this problem important enough: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/45348

Answer (score 55):

For me the issue was that when I installed from `jdk-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg` the installation did not update the `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK` directory link to the new 1.8 JDK. This may not have been the issue of the original question but it was the solution for me when I encountered the same error message.

I don't know why the installer doesn't link it and to make matters more confusing, the path is different depending on whether you installed it from Oracle or Apple. See [Mac OS X 10.6.7 Java Path Current JDK confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141180/mac-os-x-10-6-7-java-path-current-jdk-confusing)

I did the following to fix my environment

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo rm CurrentJDK
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<installed_jdk_version>.jdk/Contents CurrentJDK
```

Comment: Same problem, and fixing the "CurrentJDK" cured it for me.

Comment: I am root but still get `rm: CurrentJDK: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Had to turn off rootless: `https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11`

Answer (score 27):

The solution which worked for me:

In Eclipse, I had a wrong run configuration in my Maven build. Go to

> Run Configurations -> JRE [Tab]

and set the runtime to Java 8.

Comment: Perfect finding...was struggling since long time with this...Above setting helped..

Answer (score 27):

I ran into the same problem on my CentOS 6.5 system.

`java -version` returned a Java 8 version, but `javac -version` returned a Java 7 version.

I had to run the following commands to get all kinds of Java-related symlinks point to my JDK 8 installation:

```
sudo alternatives --config java
sudo alternatives --config javac
sudo alternatives --config jre_openjdk
sudo alternatives --config java_sdk_openjdk
```

Comment: in my case it was **sudo update-alternatives --config javac** Are you sure "alternatives" is not a typo?

Comment: `update-alternatives` is relevant to Debian and Ubuntu, whereas `alternatives` is relevant to CentOS/RedHat.

Answer (score 14):

Your `JAVA_HOME` is being overridden from somewhere else. Try echoing in `mvn` right before java invocation.

Comment: Somehow, I didn't notice this answer until too late, but it would have revealed the fact that `~/.mavenrc` was overriding JAVA_HOME, so +1.

Comment: I think specifically settings JAVA_HOME (e.g. in .bash_login using export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexex/java_home -v 1.8`) is the best option

Comment: I agree with @scravy - ```export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)```

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can also get the "invalid target release" error with Java 11

> ```
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-
> plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project projects-migration: 
> Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 1.11 -> [Help 1]
> ```

if you set `1.11` instead of just `11` in the POM.

Incorrect:

```
<java.version>1.11</java.version>
```

Correct:

```
<java.version>11</java.version>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, needed 2 steps to make correct:

1. Ensure `JAVA_HOME` is set pointing correctly to JDK;
2. JDK and JRE in eclipse should point the same version.

For me 1 step was right, 2nd step had problem. In eclipse » Project's properties » Build Path » Installed JRE » point to JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an early access release of 1.8.  Now that is has been released, you should install the released version.

Check you maven installation to see if you have a configuration associated with it that specifies a particular JDK.  Occasionally there are wrapper scripts which reset JAVA_HOME prior to maven launch, or the maven executable is launched in a wrapper that refers to a config file that could bind you to a particular JVM.

Comment: Exactly what am I looking for? There's a JRE folder there (as well as bin, db, lib, and include). As far as I can tell, it seems to be the same as the other JREs. I downloaded this from https://jdk8.java.net/download.html. And it works with Eclipse (I tested a lambda).

Comment: The latest release of Java 8 is 1.8.0_05.  The jdk1.8.0_20-ea indicates it's the 20th EARLY ACCESS release of Java 8, in other words, the 20th sneak peek of what will eventually become 1.8.0, which is now in it's fifth "patch release" or 1.8.0_05.  Basically, once you can get a non-ea build, go for it.

Comment: I just tried 1.8.0_05 (actually, I tried that first) and Maven still does not recognize it. All I did was set `JAVA_HOME` (which other posts seem to imply is all that's needed). As an aside, is 1.8.0_05 newer than 1.8.0_20-ea?

Comment: Yes, 1.8.0_20-ea is earlier than 1.8.0_05.  From oldest to newest, it's more ordered 1.8.0_20-ea, 1.8.0, 1.8.0_05.  Check a couple of things.  `which java` and then a `ls -l` of the returned value (as it can redirect you independently of the `JAVA_HOME` and also check your `PATH` environment variable, as it might be overriding which `java` is found before you get to the items you are checking.

Comment: Thanks. I should be using 1.8.0_05 then. I was confused over which version was the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven within a continuous integration server be sure to check it's settings as it may override the JDK used by Maven. For Jenkins, I had to add the new 1.8 JDK in the general settings and configure my project to use it.