# Unable to launch eclipse on Mac - No Java virtual machine

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm unable to launch eclipse after I messed up with Current and CurrentJDK by executing following commands from post [Can't get Maven to recognize Java 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705877/cant-get-maven-to-recognize-java-1-8)

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo rm Current
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<installed_jdk_version>.jdk/Contents Current
sudo rm CurrentJDK
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<installed_jdk_version>.jdk/Contents CurrentJDK
```

I'm getting below error:
[image]

I also tried to reinstall java. But installer is terminating without completing or without giving any error.
Please help as I'm completely stuck due to this.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, why did you rm the system folder? In general do not, modify your system's lib files, unless you completely know what you are doing or what would be the side effects.

Now, you can download a dmg with a JDK, run the installer and restart your system. By the way try to remove the sym link that you created on the third line.

Have a look on the notes  [here](http://javapapo.blogspot.gr/2013/12/setup-your-java-development-environment.html) (for the manual way of installing Java/Maven) on your mac.

There is also a tool called HomeBrew/Cask that eventually helps you deal with that kind of installation and path issues a lot easier. See [here](http://javapapo.blogspot.gr/2015/08/brew-and-brew-cask-package-manager-for.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac).

Hope that helps!

Comment: ` vi .bash_profile ` is creating new file. is this ok?

Comment: go through the notes, with care and it will work. You can eventually try installing brew and brew cask, and it will do most of the work for you.